# Differential equation system (coupled)

Tags: differential

I have a system with some differential equations. The equations are coupled, in this way: $f'_n(x)=Af_{n-1}(x)+Bf_{n+1}(x)+Cf_n$. I would like to solve the system. I am a beginner in Mathematica. Could someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Do you intend to solve the system numerically? Please note that there is also a site specifically dedicated to [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Numerically or analytically, it's not the case. I want to solve it :).

Comment: Thank you too for this link. I didn't know about https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/